# Our tiler put Grout Boost on after laying grout, thinking it was grout sealer. What should we do?

Tags: tile, grout

Our tiler made an error and put Grout Boost on after laying the grout, thinking it was grout sealer.  What should we do?

Will Grout Boost act as sealer when applied after grout is put down and dry?

Or should we put sealer over the grout and Grout Boost?

Or wash the Grout Boost off then put down grout sealer?

Or tear up the tile and start over... hope not!!

Answer (score 1):

Grout Boost is meant to be mixed with the grout before installation.  If you can clean it off and the grout looks ok afterwards, I imagine you could use regular grout sealer.

Personally, if you are paying them to do the job, I'd want them to dig out the existing grout and re-grout it.  There is no need to tear up all the tiles, just the grout.

You might try emailing the folks at groutboost.com and see what they recommend specifically.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.groutboost.com/pdfs/GB_AdvncPro_FAQ.pdf
this link will tell you all you need to know about grout boost.

Comment: Links tend to go AWOL after some time.  While linking is fine, please give a brief summary of the linked page so that your answer will be preserved in the future.  And welcome to DIY.  Enjoy.